# Did Brodie Smith throw a Frisbee to somebody on a zipline?

Tags: sport

[Brodie Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brodie_Smith_(ultimate)) is a flying-disc trick-shot performer. He claims to have successfully thrown a Frisbee disc to be caught by someone zooming by on a [zip-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip-line).

A [Vine video](https://vine.co/v/edXEbHBE7nE) (advertised by [Smith's Twitter account](https://twitter.com/Brodiesmith21/status/631612395014615040))
shows the stunt.

It appears, from more angles and in higher resolution, as the first stunt on this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYnw2BMsU2A).

It was also reported in the media, such as [SB Nation](http://www.sbnation.com/2015/8/12/9145841/trick-shot-artist-snags-frisbee-while-riding-zipline), and in [SportsCentre's Top 10](https://twitter.com/Brodiesmith21/status/631868576354308096).

Did that throw happen?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Given that: (1) you have seen footage of the stunt from various angles in high-resolution, (2) it is in keeping with other skills Brodie Smith has demonstrated and (3) there is nothing that appears to be out of the realm of feasibility here, what *sort* of evidence could appear in an answer that would convince you that the video was real?

Comment: Also, though I speak from a position of ignorance when it comes to how difficult it is to throw a frisbee, to me, this doesn't seem to be that far-fetched of a feat, any more than "shooting ahead of the duck" is. You estimate how fast the guy is going, in what direction (for a zip line, that's trivial), then *aim where the guy is **going** to be*, and throw it at `T-(speed of moving target / distance to intersection point)` (and it doesn't hurt that if you're off by an arm radius or less, the other guy will do his best to reach for the frisbee).

Comment: As you can see from this [behind the scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09NUGAyhLSc&feature=iv&src_vid=xYnw2BMsU2A&annotation_id=annotation_2150838673) video, most of these stunts took multiple tries.

Comment: Voting to close. Such questions tend to dilute the value of this SE.

Comment: -1 because the question seems to be demonstrating unwarranted skepticism about the veracity of the videos. Not VTCing since it does seem to be a notable claim.

Comment: @nomenagentis I don't believe it's a notable claim about scientific skepticism. Allowing questions about specific trick-shot videos is like allowing "Is this stage magic illusion real?" or "Is this advertisement photoshopped?" I think such questions undermine not just the site's charter, but it's purpose: Encouraging skeptical thought and reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

In this [behind the scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a65MSg2gn2E&t=5m47s) video, Brodie and the other participants describe the feat:

> after every throw, we had to reset, and it was like a 15 minute reset
>
> [...]
>
> Seth is getting tired [...] cause he's done it 10 times [...] so we threw in Stratacous [...] and what second try... third try, Brodie nails it

Answer (score 0):

Trick shot videos rely on a simple adage: **[if at first you don't succeed](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=brodie%20smith%20bloopers), try try again.**

Any talented disc thrower who rented a zipline for an afternoon and made repeated attempts would eventually manage it. Vine, of course, does not show you the misses. There could have been dozens.

See also similar shots [to a moving car](https://youtu.be/-YGsTfSl3-g) and [to a water skier](https://youtu.be/Hc2stdqp7KQ?t=2m10s).

It's not nearly as difficult as it looks, if failures don't count. I personally have made throws to moving skaters at similar distance (~40% success rate) and Mr Smith is surely better at it than most people (including me).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer. Just that there is nothing that appears to be out of the realm of feasibility, which I think would make a good comment, but I already made it!